# Chrome default MinLength Error

Tags: css, html

I have a `input` field through which users can submit some data.

But, if the data character length is less than 10, then they won't be able to submit.

```
<input type="text" minlength="10" placeholder="Submit" class="dataSubmit" />
```

Which means, in case a user tries to submit data with less than 10 characters then google chrome shows this error `Please lengthen this text to 10 characters or more (you're currently using 3 characters)`.

But I want to change this error message to `More data required`.

So, how can I change this default message?

Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

We can define the `id` for input and add custom validation using JavaScript.

```
<input id="data" type="text" minlength="10" placeholder="Submit" class="dataSubmit" />
```

In JavaScript, we can add custom validation for input something like below :

```
var data = document.getElementById("data");
data.addEventListener("input", function (event) {
  if (data.validity.typeMismatch) {
    data.setCustomValidity("Updated Error message");
  } else {
    data.setCustomValidity("");
  }
});
```